# undefined symbol: ompi_mpi_char in MPI.so

Tags: python, mpi, openmpi, hpc, mpi4py

I am trying to run a python code on a HPC server. I am using mpi4py library for parallel computing on multiple nodes in python.

I wrote a simple bash script run.sh as:

```
#!/bin/sh
#SBATCH -N 2      # nodes requested
#SBATCH -n 6      # tasks requested
#SBATCH -o outfile  # send stdout to outfile
#SBATCH -e errfile  # send stderr to errfile
#SBATCH -t 0:01:00  # time requested in hour:minute:second
module load python intel/compiler/64/16.0.2/2016.2.181 openmpi/gcc/64/1.10.1
srun -n 6 python code.py
```

and ran the script using 
    $ sbatch run.sh.

I got an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code.py", line 10, in <module>
    from mpi4py import MPI
ImportError: /home/user007/.local/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/mpi4py/MPI.so: undefined symbol: ompi_mpi_char
srun: error: cn111: task 5: Exited with exit code 1
```

The import error was not there when I was manually importing MPI from mpi4py by simply running python on my shell and then typing from mpi4py import MPI.

Comment: you can try to `ldd /home/user007/.local/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/mpi4py/MPI.so` both from the shell and the slurm script. do you see any difference ?

Comment: run `module purge` before the `module load` to make sure Slurm does not propagate another MPI env to the job